# How does a packages typescript code is consumed by other packages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, transpiler

When a package with `typescript` code is imported. will the consumer use typescript or transpiled code (e.g. typescript to ES5).

Scenario #1: If the consumer uses transpiled code (which is not in typescript). How is VSCode able to recommend auto completions from the packages types?

Scenario #2: If the packages are served with typescript files.

1. What happens if the consumer is not using typescript?
2. How does the bundling at the consumer end happen?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Scenario #1: This is the most common scenario for public NPM packages, editors use external `.d.ts` files that contain type declarations
Scenario #2: I've only seen this with internal libraries

- 1) You'd need to compile the TS by yourself, but that would probably not be necessary because there will almost always be a compiled-to-js version of the library, too
- 2) This could go many ways, best case is that the library gives you a pre-optimized JS that is just bundled with your code, worst case is that you have to make sure you have all the right dependencies installed for the library to be able to be compiled with your code and they need to be compatible with the dependencies you're using yourself. In my opinion this isn't worth the hassle, having type declarations for NPM packages is sufficient for the level of type safety TypeScript can provide.

## The Long Version

There are dozens of variants how people distribute their TypeScript based code via NPM. Most big libraries I know ship their compiled (and often minified) JS and add `.d.ts` declaration files for editor support - these may be hand-written or produced by using `tsc` from a codebase. VSCode uses its TypeScript language server for JavaScript files, too, so in many cases it doesn't even need additional declaration files to provide you with basic autocompletion. Libraries can declare a `types` field inside the `package.json`, VSCode and other editors [will find types there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html). There is a rather large community that maintains mostly inofficial type declarations for most libraries on [definitelytyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) - you may be out of luck for obscure ones.

## A few examples

### Material UI

- [Is written in JavaScript](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Box/Box.js)
- [Has hand-written TypeScript declarations (which may or may not be accurate)](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Box/Box.d.ts)

### React

- [Is written in JavaScript](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOM.js)
- Provides no TypeScript declarations with the NPM package but [VSCode knows where to find inofficial external ones](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)

### Angular

- [Is written in TypeScript](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/core.ts)
- [Uses the deprecated `typings` field to point to its type declarations](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/package.json#L12)

### jQuery

- [Is written in JavaScript](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)
- [Again, has no provided type declarations but your editor probably knows how to fetch inoffical ones](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)

### Seneca

- [Is written in JavaScript](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca/blob/master/lib/common.js)
- [Has inoffical type declarations that are two years old at the time of writing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/seneca) - good luck finding out whether the API really hasn't changed

## Important take-aways:

- There is no single way people do things in the JS ecosystem and by extension the TS ecosystem
- Most type declarations you're using are not official ones but the ones maintained by the community, [mostly on definitelytyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)
- The types might be lying to you (may be out-of-date, just be plain wrong or for an older TS version)
- TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, it comes with all the same gotchas by definition
- All types are erased at runtime, in the end you're running plain JavaScript with all that this entails